# Cannot open source file “nuitrack/Nuitrack.h”

Tags: c++

I am trying to run Nuitrack bodytracking with my Intel Realsense Camera, I am using VisualStudio 2017 and trying to run this sample project

http://download.3divi.com/Nuitrack/doc/nuitrack_console_sample_2src_2main_8cpp-example.html.

I successfully CMAKE the project, however when I run it on Visual Studio I get the error cannot open source file “nuitrack/Nuitrack.h”

I followed the installation step and the sample executables work for me, its just my Visual Studio projects are unable to import nuitrack.h

My environment variables look like this

[image: Home Variables]

Comment: I think you have an extra `nuitrack` in your include path. Do you really have a `nuitrack/nuitrack/nuitrack` folder?

Comment: That is a good observation but unfortunately that is in fact the path.

Comment: Please do not post screendumps as images. All questions on stackoverflow must include all pertinent information in the question itself, ***as plain text***. Although the text portion of this question is readable, the image is not, and looks quite tiny. If someone can't read the question, they can't help you with an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you show that the properties dialog is from the right build settings?

For example your **active build target**
x64 Debug
[image]

is also where you set the include path?
[image]